# Account made with Azure AD and problems with Group Permissions

Tags: active-directory, azure

Is it possible to create a on-premise AD account and link the Azure AD account to it?  Overall, I want to avoid rebuilding a account.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: More details , context, the "why", what you've tried and the research that you've done . All these things will make your question better. Right now there isnt enough information to go on, and you haven't demonstrated any effort on your own part.